# Override wordpress plugin function without edit plugin files

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to override a function of the hivepress plugin located in `includes/components/class-router.php` without modifying the plugin files, I spent hours searching, I already tried to add this code in the functions.php file of my theme

```php
add_action('get_url', 'my_get_url');
functions my_get_url($name, $query = [], $filter = false) {
    return "testurl.com";
}
```

but no change where there should be one.
Here is the link to the documentation of this function: https://hivepress.github.io/code-reference/classes/HivePress-Components-Router.html#method_get_url
Thanks in advance

Comment: what are you trying to override the functionality to?

Comment: looking at the source code for hive press i dont see any hooks for the `get_url` function.  but following it to `get_routes` there is a filter that might help: https://hivepress.github.io/code-reference/files/hivepress-includes-components-class-router.html#source-view.75

Comment: @mikerojas this hook doesn't fit my needs, in fact, I want to override the get_url function to change the url returned to integrate polylang